# How to get and/or of Booleans in python

Tags: python

How to get or/and of Booleans in python. For example I have a list of Booleans

```
lst = [True, True, False, False, True]
```

I want to define another Boolean variable based on condition in this lst. What is the best way of returning True if any one item is True within lst. Also how can I return True with the condition that all items are True within lst

Comment: Take a look at the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) functions. These are built in and always available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks. I solved using the following:

```
x = all(lst)
y = any(lst)
print(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any) and the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#all) function is the way to go:

```
lst = [True, True, False, False, True]

x=all(lst)
y=any(lst)

print(x,y)
```

Comment: I don't see the need to compare with `True`here. I think `x = any(i for i in lst)` or just `x = any(lst)` (the same for `all`) is just neater and more readable.

Comment: Generator expressions are commonly used with `all` and `any` because you usually don't already have a sequence of Boolean values and have to create one. `lst`, however, *is* a sequence of Boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

If all elements of your list are booleans, the faster and simplest way is

```py
lst = [True, True, False, True]
condition = False not in lst

# in other words
(False not in lst) == all(lst)
(True in lst) == any(lst)
```

`condition` will be `False` if even one `False` in list